# getFragmentManager() returns null, with android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment support libraray

Tags: android-fragments, mapactivity

here is the fragment dialog:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;  
public static class SensorMeasurmentsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static SensorMeasurmentsDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {

        SensorMeasurmentsDialogFragment frag = new SensorMeasurmentsDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;

        @Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

the call to it is done from a regular activity not from a fragmentActivity because 
my activity already extends mapActivity.

```
m_measurmentDlg=SensorMeasurmentsDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.app_name);
m_measurmentDlg.show(m_measurmentDlg.getFragmentManager(),"measurments");
```

any idea why is it Null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activity must extend from FragmentActivity for you to be able to use Fragments. You might have to use a workaround at the moment until Google updates their map library.

You might have to use a modified compatibility lib such as this one:

https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps

Answer (score 1):

In one of my fragments, I was using `replace` so when I used `add` it worked good!
might help you

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem also.  The problem happens with setRetainInstance(true) only.  My workaround is to use the parent activity's FragmentManager object instead of the DialogFragment's FragmentManager.